# Spring boot management.metrics.export not created bean in case enable set false

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When I set `enabled`:`false` here

```
management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      tomcat: false
      jvm: false
      process: false
      hikaricp: false
      system: false
      jdbc: false
      http: false
      logback: false
    tags:
      env: local
      service: my-service
    export:
      statsd:
        host: localhost
        port: 8089
        flavor: telegraf
        step: 10s
        enabled: false
```

spring-boot throws the error
`Consider defining a bean of type 'io.micrometer.statsd.StatsdMeterRegistry' in your configuration.`

FYI: it works perfectly fine if `enabled` is set `true`.

I expect it to not send the metrics in case it's set as false not completely ignore defining the bean.

Here is how I'm using it.

```
@Component
public class MordorMetricsRegistry {

    private CompositeMeterRegistry compositeMeterRegistry;
    private StatsdMeterRegistry statsdMeterRegistry;

    public MordorMetricsRegistry(StatsdMeterRegistry statsdMeterRegistry) {
        this.statsdMeterRegistry = statsdMeterRegistry;

        this.compositeMeterRegistry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
        this.compositeMeterRegistry.add(this.statsdMeterRegistry);
    }

    public void monitorCaffeineCache(String name, LoadingCache cache) {
        CaffeineCacheMetrics.monitor(compositeMeterRegistry, cache, name, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added the code where I'm using StatsdMeterRegistry

Comment: What's trying to inject the `StatsdMeterRegistry`? If no export is enabled, Spring Boot should still configure a `MeterRegistry` for you, but it will be a `SimpleMeterRegistry`. Perhaps you can change your injection point to consume `MeterRegistry` rather than `StatsdMeterRegistry`.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson please check the post again, I've edited it to add my code.

If I'll consume MeterRegistry directly how will it send metrics to Statsd?

Comment: Why do you have that code? Your composite only contains a single meter registry so  it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: I have written it like that in case in future we have to export metrics to multiple monitoring systems, I'll just add it in .yaml and add the registry for same in my code and add it to the composite.

Comment: Spring Boot's auto-configuration will already do that for you. If there are multiple `MeterRegistry` beans in the context, it will create a `CompositeMeterRegistry` that contains them all. If you just inject `MeterRegistry`, all this will happen without you having to change anything: you'll either get a composite when there are multiple meter registries or you'll get the single non-composite meter registry.

Comment: That clarifies everything @AndyWilkinson thanks a lot 